# Need to reset network adapter after sleep (Vista)

Tags: networking, windows-vista, network-adapter

I have a Dell Inspiron M1330 running Windows Vista Ultimate.  Ever since I moved into a new apartment (and had to start using a hard-wired connection via Ethernet) I have had to reset the network adapter every time the computer wakes up from sleep.

Specifically, I have to open the networking and sharing window, go to view status, diagnose, and finally reset the network adapter.  After this the connection works fine.  Is this a matter of changing some settings on my machine?  Or is it a problem with the network at large?  If the latter, is there a script or something to take some of the tedium out of this process?

Comment: Don't have the problem on my Sony laptop running Vista.  But have you tried unplugging and replugging the network cable to reset it?  (Your problem probably has something to do with IP address assignment.)

Comment: You might try Properties/Configure/Power Management and toggle the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" attribute.